# Javascript Window object Cross-Domain accessible properties

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

So I realize that with two windows of different domains, there is very little information that can exchanged. Withholding of course using `postMessage` or similar methods, what `specific properties` can two windows of different domains acquire?

For one simple example, if I open a child popup of a different domain, I know that the parent has access to the `closed` property of the child. Is there a list of other accessible properties?

Comment: name is readable anywhere and self-writable.